# Reverse direction on borders in pygame

Tags: python, loops, pygame, border, collision

I am trying to make a space invaders game using pygame, but I can't figure out how to make the `ufo` (enemy) object goes left and right every time it hits the border. Basically I want it to it look like this: https://www.youtube.com/watchv=jM0v4VemWu8&ab_channel=AndrijaOluji%C4%87AndrijaOluji%C4%87

The problem I am having is in this part of code:

```
UFO_VEL = 5
def ufo_movement(ufo, UFO_VEL):
    ufo.x -= UFO_VEL
    if ufo.x == 0:
        ufo.x += UFO_VEL
```

It seems like a really easy task and I manage to make it work in a similar project with Tkinter but in pygame it gets stuck in the infinte loop while pygame.display.update() so it reaches 0, it inverts the direction for one frame, and than it starts again with the original direction ( ufo.x -= UFO_VEL ), so effectively ufo.x gets stuck between 0 and 5 and the spaceship doesn't seem to move. I tried everything, even drawing a line (Rect) as a border and make it bounce when it hits the line (UserEvent) but I just can't manage to make it work. Here is my full code:

```
import os
import pygame

# WIN CONSTANTS
WIDTH, HEIGHT = 500, 700
WIN = pygame.display.set_mode(((WIDTH, HEIGHT)))
pygame.display.set_caption("First Game!")

# COLORS LIST
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
FPS = 60

# BACKGROUND IMAGE
BG = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("spacebg.jpg"))
BG_RESIZED = pygame.transform.scale(BG, (WIDTH, HEIGHT))

# SPACESHIP CONSTANTS
SPACESHIP_WIDTH = 100
SPACESHIP_HEIGHT = 40
SPACESHIP_IMAGE = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("spaceship.png"))
# Resize image
SPACESHIP = pygame.transform.scale(SPACESHIP_IMAGE, (SPACESHIP_WIDTH, SPACESHIP_HEIGHT))  
SPACESHIP_VEL = 10

# UFO CONSTANTS
UFO_WIDTH = 100
UFO_HEIGHT = 40
UFO_IMAGE = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("ufo.png"))
UFO = pygame.transform.scale(UFO_IMAGE, (UFO_WIDTH, UFO_HEIGHT))  # resize image
UFO_VEL = 5
UFO_HIT = pygame.USEREVENT + 1  # Create custom event

# BULLET CONSTANTS
BULLET_VEL = 7


def draw_window(space_ship, ufo, bullets, UFO_VEL):
    WIN.blit(BG_RESIZED, (0, 0))
    WIN.blit(SPACESHIP, (space_ship.x, space_ship.y))  # Insert one object to window
    WIN.blit(UFO, (ufo.x, ufo.y))

    for bul in bullets:
        pygame.draw.rect(WIN, WHITE, bul)

    pygame.display.update()  # update at maximum FPS, FUNDAMENTAL
    # IS THIS THE ISSUE? 


def spaceship_move(space_ship):
    keys_pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys_pressed[pygame.K_a] and space_ship.x > 10:  # LEFT
        space_ship.x -= SPACESHIP_VEL
    if keys_pressed[pygame.K_d] and space_ship.x < 390:  # RIGHT
        space_ship.x += SPACESHIP_VEL
    if keys_pressed[pygame.K_w] and space_ship.y > 500:  # UP
        space_ship.y -= SPACESHIP_VEL
    if keys_pressed[pygame.K_s] and space_ship.y < 640:  # DOWN
        space_ship.y += SPACESHIP_VEL


def handle_bullets(bullets, space_ship):
    for bul in bullets:
        bul.y -= BULLET_VEL
        if ufo.colliderect(bul):
            pygame.event.post(pygame.event.Event(UFO_HIT))
            bullets.remove(bul)
        if bul.y < 5:
            bullets.remove(bul)


def ufo_movement(ufo, UFO_VEL): # ISSUE HERE ##########
    ufo.x -= UFO_VEL
    if ufo.x <= 0:
        ufo.x += UFO_VEL


def main():
    space_ship = pygame.Rect(200, 640, SPACESHIP_WIDTH, SPACESHIP_HEIGHT)
    ufo = pygame.Rect(200, 30, UFO_WIDTH, UFO_HEIGHT) ######## DEFINING UFO OBJECT 
    bullets = []
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()  # Count FPS
    run = True
    while run:  # while run is true the game will stay open
        clock.tick(FPS)  # Ensure the frame rate doesn't go over FPS var
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = False
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                    bullet = pygame.Rect(space_ship.x + space_ship.width // 2 - 5,
                                     space_ship.y + space_ship.height // 2, 10, 5)
                    bullets.append(bullet)

        ufo_movement(ufo, UFO_VEL) # CALLING AUTOMATIC BOUNCING

        draw_window(space_ship, ufo, bullets, UFO_VEL)
        spaceship_move(space_ship)
        handle_bullets(bullets, space_ship)

    pygame.quit()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem of your code is it only move right once and stop move,to solve that u should add a direction to move

u could try this

```
import os
import pygame

# WIN CONSTANTS
WIDTH, HEIGHT = 500, 700
WIN = pygame.display.set_mode(((WIDTH, HEIGHT)))
pygame.display.set_caption("First Game!")

# COLORS LIST
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
FPS = 60

# BACKGROUND IMAGE
BG = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("spacebg.jpg"))
BG_RESIZED = pygame.transform.scale(BG, (WIDTH, HEIGHT))

# SPACESHIP CONSTANTS
SPACESHIP_WIDTH = 100
SPACESHIP_HEIGHT = 40
SPACESHIP_IMAGE = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("spaceship.jpg"))
# Resize image
SPACESHIP = pygame.transform.scale(
    SPACESHIP_IMAGE, (SPACESHIP_WIDTH, SPACESHIP_HEIGHT))
SPACESHIP_VEL = 10

# UFO CONSTANTS
UFO_WIDTH = 100
UFO_HEIGHT = 40
UFO_IMAGE = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("ufo.jpg"))
UFO = pygame.transform.scale(
    UFO_IMAGE, (UFO_WIDTH, UFO_HEIGHT))  # resize image
UFO_VEL = 5
UFO_HIT = pygame.USEREVENT + 1  # Create custom event

# BULLET CONSTANTS
BULLET_VEL = 7


def draw_window(space_ship, ufo, bullets, UFO_VEL):
    WIN.blit(BG_RESIZED, (0, 0))
    # Insert one object to window
    WIN.blit(SPACESHIP, (space_ship.x, space_ship.y))
    WIN.blit(UFO, (ufo.x, ufo.y))

    for bul in bullets:
        pygame.draw.rect(WIN, WHITE, bul)

    pygame.display.update()  # update at maximum FPS, FUNDAMENTAL
    # IS THIS THE ISSUE?


def spaceship_move(space_ship):
    keys_pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys_pressed[pygame.K_a] and space_ship.x > 10:  # LEFT
        space_ship.x -= SPACESHIP_VEL
    if keys_pressed[pygame.K_d] and space_ship.x < 390:  # RIGHT
        space_ship.x += SPACESHIP_VEL
    if keys_pressed[pygame.K_w] and space_ship.y > 500:  # UP
        space_ship.y -= SPACESHIP_VEL
    if keys_pressed[pygame.K_s] and space_ship.y < 640:  # DOWN
        space_ship.y += SPACESHIP_VEL


def handle_bullets(bullets, space_ship):
    for bul in bullets:
        bul.y -= BULLET_VEL
        if ufo.colliderect(bul):
            pygame.event.post(pygame.event.Event(UFO_HIT))
            bullets.remove(bul)
        if bul.y < 5:
            bullets.remove(bul)


def ufo_movement(ufo, UFO_VEL, direction_left):
    if direction_left:
        ufo_left(ufo, UFO_VEL)
    else:
        ufo_right(ufo, UFO_VEL)
    direction_left = update_direction(ufo, direction_left)
    return direction_left


def ufo_left(ufo, UFO_VEL):
    ufo.x -= UFO_VEL


def ufo_right(ufo, UFO_VEL):
    ufo.x += UFO_VEL


def update_direction(ufo, direction_left):
    if ufo.x <= 0:
        direction_left = False
    if ufo.x >= WIDTH-SPACESHIP_WIDTH:
        direction_left = True

    return direction_left


def main():
    space_ship = pygame.Rect(200, 640, SPACESHIP_WIDTH, SPACESHIP_HEIGHT)
    ufo = pygame.Rect(200, 30, UFO_WIDTH, UFO_HEIGHT)  # DEFINING UFO OBJECT
    bullets = []
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()  # Count FPS
    run = True

    direction_left = True
    while run:  # while run is true the game will stay open
        clock.tick(FPS)  # Ensure the frame rate doesn't go over FPS var
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = False
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                    bullet = pygame.Rect(space_ship.x + space_ship.width // 2 - 5,
                                         space_ship.y + space_ship.height // 2, 10, 5)
                    bullets.append(bullet)

        # CALLING AUTOMATIC BOUNCING
        direction_left = ufo_movement(ufo, UFO_VEL, direction_left)

        draw_window(space_ship, ufo, bullets, UFO_VEL)
        spaceship_move(space_ship)
        handle_bullets(bullets, space_ship)

    pygame.quit()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: this finally works perfectly! Is there a difference in how pygame handle Rect and Sprites? because I found a lot of tutorial where my code would have been enough to bounce a Rect, but here I am working with a Sprite (Rect = draw(), Sprite = blit(). Is it right?

Comment: I not quit sure what's  the `Rect and Sprites` here,is there any code i can see?

Answer (score 0):

Add a variable for the movement of the ufo in global namespace:

```py
ufo_move_x = UFO_VEL
```

Change `ufo_move_x` when the ufo hits the borders:

```py
def ufo_movement(ufo, UFO_VEL):
    global ufo_move_x

    if ufo.left <= 0:
        ufo_move_x = UFO_VEL
    elif ufo.right >= 500:
        ufo_move_x = -UFO_VEL 

    ufo.x += ufo_move_x
```

Comment: @MatteoScalas The code works fine for me. Did you forget global `ufo_move_x`? Is this a new question?